# installing firefox and xvfb on amazon linux

Tags: linux, firefox, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, xvfb

I am trying to add firefox on amazon linux since few days but I am not able to make it work. 
I want to use xvfb to run firefox as a headless browser.

I installed both using `sudo yum install package`command but when i try to run it as

```
$ Xvfb :1
$ export DISPLAY=:1
$ firefox
```

it is giving error "cannot open display: :1

can anyone help me with this ? or anyone can help me to install it properly so it works !

Thanks in advance

Comment: I can't even install firefox on Amazon linux